# I stuck on android method FloatMath.floor API does not issue

Tags: android, android-studio, window, floor

Method:

```
@Override
protected boolean isReadyForPullEnd() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    float exactContentHeight = FloatMath.floor(mRefreshableView.getContentHeight() * mRefreshableView.getScale());
    return mRefreshableView.getScrollY() >= (exactContentHeight - mRefreshableView.getHeight());
}
```

Output:
`Error:(116, 39) error: cannot find symbol method floor(float)`

Any one idea to fix this one?

Comment: more details
- Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
- Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 17):

FloatMath utility class is deprecated. Use Math.floor instead.

Comment: Not just deprectated [but](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/FloatMath.html) "All methods were removed from the public API in version 23."

Comment: when I turn it to 'Math.floor' it says "Incompatible type Required: float Found: double" what should I do?

Comment: @AphikritGerbertSaravasri cast it to float like this.

float exactContentHeight = Math.floor((float)mRefreshableView.getContentHeight() * mRefreshableView.getScale());

Answer (score 8):

FloatMath and getScale() both are deprecated. use the following code instead

```
double exactContentHeight = Math.floor(mRefreshableView.getContentHeight() * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```